# ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: there is no live location in the message to edit

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I Want to Send My Live Location to telegram bot users, Bot I got This Error:

> ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: there is no live location in the message to edit

How Should I Solve?

**Module:** (https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api)

**Code:**

```
bot.on('callback_query', msg => {
    if (msg.data == `ourlivelocation`) {
        bot.editMessageLiveLocation(32.2624884, 53.4246188, {
            parse_mode: 'Markdown',
            message_id: msg.message.message_id,
            chat_id: msg.message.chat.id,
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard: livelocationKeyboard
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Where is `livelocationKeyboard`?

Comment: ```const livelocationKeyboard = [[{
    text: ``,
    callback_data: `en`
}]]``` , I don't know how should I Solve!

Comment: And where is send location code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send live location first.

Use `sendLocation` method with `live_period`, just like the following instance:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: I don't think something useful can be done with an ID of a user, if the user do not actively request a bot, but it can be a good idea to delete your ID and username from the image, just in case...